# Datatables sorting in PHP with formated numbers

Tags: php, datatables

i have an issue, and cannot find any solution.
I have a database, from there i selecting a lot of info, and than counting this data.

```
 $table->td(              
            array($row->mailing_id, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array($row->mailing_unique_id, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array($row->mailing_name, "width=\"300\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array($row->campaign_id, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array($row->segment_name, "width=\"100\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""), 
            array($row->total_sent, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(@$viewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id], "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(@number_format((@$viewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id] * 100)/$row->total_sent,  2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(number_format(@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id],0, '.', '.'), "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(@number_format((@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id]*100)/$row->total_sent,2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(@number_format((@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id] * 100)/@$viewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id], 2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(number_format(@$crossviewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id],0, '.', '.'), "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(number_format(@$crossleadsSum[$row->mailing_unique_id],0, '.', '.'), "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(@number_format((@$crossleadsSum[$row->mailing_unique_id] * 100)/@$crossviewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id], 2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
            array(@number_format(((@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id]+@$crossleadsSum[$row->mailing_unique_id])/$row->total_sent)*100, 2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\"")
           );
```

But when i displaying all the data in DataTables, sorting there is not right. Table thinks that 1.800 is less than 999, But it is thousands seperator. Data is going like this:

```
999
888
5.656
4.655
322
2.333
122
```

EDIT-----------------

This is the main query:

```
$query = sprintf("
           SELECT stat_mailings.mailing_id, stat_mailings.cat_id, stat_mailings.mailing_name, stat_mailings.mailing_unique_id, stat_mailings.segment_id,
            stat_mailings.campaign_id, stat_mailings.landing_page, stat_mailings.total_sent, pecumail_segments.segment_name, categories.category FROM `stat_mailings`
            JOIN pecumail_segments ON stat_mailings.segment_id=pecumail_segments.segment_id
            JOIN categories ON stat_mailings.cat_id=categories.id
```

This is my code, where i'm printing all the data:

```
 $table = new datatable("100%", "border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-left: -135px;\""); 

   $table->th("Mailing ID", "Unique id", "Mailing", "UTM campaign", "Segment", "Vezonden", "Views", "CTR", "Leads", "STL","Conversie", "Crossviews", "Crossleads","Crossconv","STLa");


   $analyzedata = getAnalyze();
   $leads = getLeads();
   $views = getViews();
   $crossviews = getCrossViews();
   $crossleads = getCrossLeads();



      while ($row1 = $leads->fetch_object()) {  
        $leadsData = count($row1->pema_mid);        
        @$leadssum[$row1->pema_mid] += $leadsData; 
      } 

      while ($row2 = $views->fetch_object()) {
        $countedViews = count($row2->pema_mid);        
        @$viewSum[$row2->pema_mid] += $countedViews;
      }

      while ($row3 = $crossviews->fetch_object()) {
        $countedCrossViews = count($row3->pema_mid);        
        @$crossviewSum[$row3->pema_mid] += $countedCrossViews;
      }

       while ($row4 = $crossleads->fetch_object()) {
        $countedCrossLeads = count($row4->pema_mid);        
        @$crossleadsSum[$row4->pema_mid] += $countedCrossLeads;
      }


      while($row = $analyzedata->fetch_object()){


          $totalSent = number_format($row->total_sent, 0, '.', '.');

       $table->td(              
                array($row->mailing_id, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array($row->mailing_unique_id, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array($row->mailing_name, "width=\"300\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array($row->campaign_id, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array($row->segment_name, "width=\"100\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""), 
                array($totalSent, "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(number_format(@$viewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id],0, '.', '.'), "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(@number_format((@$viewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id] * 100)/$row->total_sent,  2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(number_format(@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id],0, '.', '.'), "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(@number_format((@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id]*100)/$row->total_sent,2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(@number_format((@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id] * 100)/@$viewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id], 2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(number_format(@$crossviewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id],0, '.', '.'), "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(number_format(@$crossleadsSum[$row->mailing_unique_id],0, '.', '.'), "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(@number_format((@$crossleadsSum[$row->mailing_unique_id] * 100)/@$crossviewSum[$row->mailing_unique_id], 2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\""),
                array(@number_format(((@$leadssum[$row->mailing_unique_id]+@$crossleadsSum[$row->mailing_unique_id])/$row->total_sent)*100, 2, '.', '.').'%', "width=\"20\" style=\" border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid;\"")
               );

 }


  echo  $html = $table->getHTML();
```

And this is my DataTable script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
        { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
        { "sType": "string" },
        { "sType": "formated-num" },
        { "sType": "percent" },
        { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
        { "sType": "percent" },
        { "sType": "percent" },
        { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
        { "sType": "percent" },
        { "sType": "percent" },
        null
    ]
} );
```

} );

Comment: You have to store the real values in a separate field in order to sort on theses

Comment: Why are you hiding all the errors? That is a bad design.

Comment: is 5.656 actually the value in your database? or are you converting it to that? in other words what are the values in the table?

Comment: Because it says division by zero, i need to have 0% if division by zero exists. So that is why i'm hiding it. If i dont do this i have empty value

Comment: @djjjuk my value in database is 5656, but when i'm displaying them, then i formating it to 5.656

Comment: @Marius, why dont you sort it from MySQL when you get the data from the database?

Comment: It has a lot of data 300.000~ items, and allways growing, so sorting from database is not good, and i need sorting for 15 columns

Comment: in that case, we need to see the code you are running to actually sort these from the database. the above code doesn't really show what you are trying to do. post the query you are doing and the code running through the results.

Comment: You can look at it now, i have edited my post. Dont say anything about  a lot of while loops, i know that :) My problem is Datatable sorting :)

Answer (score 1):

you will have to sort this from the database. looking at your code, the

```
while ($row1 = $leads->fetch_object()) { }
```

looks like it grabs an object or row from the table 1 at a time. if it does that, there is no way you can sort it afterwards. you either have to sort it from the database or sort it from the class that has the fetch_object() function - as presumably that will loop through the results and create them as objects? if that class happens to be an Iterator implementation, then you are only left with sorting it from the database as an option.

the only you can sort in PHP would be to have the value as your key and sort the array by key - but obviously that wont work in cases where you have 2 or more values that are the same as they will overwrite each other.